# Fetch data from Wikipedia using Special:Export

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, mediawiki, wikipedia-api

I am trying to fetch data from Wikipedia using [`Special:Export`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special%3aExport)

Following is my markup, i am unable to understand why it does not get into the while loop? I get no errors though. Kindly Help.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim webRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = CType(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export/Train"), HttpWebRequest)
        webRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        webRequest.Accept = "text/xml"
        webRequest.UserAgent = "foo/bar"
        Dim webResponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = CType(webRequest.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
        Dim responseStream As System.IO.Stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream
        Dim reader As System.Xml.XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(responseStream)
        Dim NS As String = "http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.4/"
        Dim doc As XPathDocument = New XPathDocument(reader)
        reader.Close()
        webResponse.Close()
        Dim myXPathNavigator As XPathNavigator = doc.CreateNavigator
        Dim nodesText As XPathNodeIterator = myXPathNavigator.SelectDescendants("text", NS, False)

        While nodesText.MoveNext
            Response.Write((nodesText.Current.InnerXml + " "))
        End While
    End Sub
```

Comment: If it does not get to the loop, what *does* it do? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: Could you please try it in your system?

Answer (score 0):

Special:Export should be POST'ed. See the [Special:Export manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parameters_to_Special:Export).

However, you should really not be doing this. Please use a [web API client library for your language of choice](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#.NET) and access the [export module](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Exporting_pages).